# Run flask as an instance attribute with route decorators?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I'm hoping to have a class which sub classes `threading.thread` and is responsible for running flask. The class should also encapsulate the flask's `route` decorator.

The `route` decorator is provided by the instance of the Flask object. I'm hoping to contain everything Flask related in the class.

This leads to the problem where to get the decorator I have to access Flask as an instance attribute. But `@self` isn't reachable as a decorator.

I know it's possible to overcome this with making Flask global for the module etc. Is there is a way to keep it contained inside a class and still achieve this?

```
import threading
from flask import Flask


class ControllableServer(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        self._flask = Flask(__name__)

    # This needs to be a decorator from an initialised flask object
    # In the examles they usually do:
    #    app = Flask(__name__)
    #    @app.route(("/endpoint", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    #    def endpoint():
    #        ....
    @self._flask.route("/endpoint", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def _endpoint(self):
        return str("Endpoint")

    def run(self):
        self._flask.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    controllable_server = ControllableServer()
    controllable_server.start()
```

Error:

```
   @self._flask.route("/endpoint", methods=['GET', 'POST']
   All│NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: No idea how to do that man I'm sorry. I would look at the codebase of some well developed packages that already do this, like `flask-restplus` or `connexion`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be addressed by using the `add_url_rule` instead of the decorator.

```
from flask import Flask, Response
import threading
import requests
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='[Thread: %(threadName)s-%(thread)d] %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class ControllableServer(threading.Thread):

    class _URLCallbackClass():
        def url_callback(self):
            return Response("Hello from url callback", 200)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(daemon=True)
        self._flask = Flask(__name__)

    def run(self):
        callback_class = ControllableServer._URLCallbackClass()
        self._flask.add_url_rule('/endpoint', 'url_callback', callback_class.url_callback)
        logger.info("Starting flask")
        self._flask.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":                                                                                                                                                                                         
    controllable_server = ControllableServer()                                                                                                                                                                     
    controllable_server.start()                                                                                                                                                                                    
    logger.info("Flask is started")                                                                                                                                                                                
    response = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/endpoint")                                                                                                                                                      
    logger.info(f"Got response: {response.text}")
```

Result:

```
[Thread: Thread-1-139887742854912] Starting flask
 * Serving Flask app "basic_flask" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
[Thread: MainThread-139887779895104] Flask is started
[Thread: Thread-1-139887742854912]  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
[Thread: Thread-2-139887733913344] 127.0.0.1 - - [03/Mar/2020 18:00:54] "GET /endpoint HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[Thread: MainThread-139887779895104] Got response: Hello from url callback
```

**Please note**

Because the rool logger was set to log thread names, we now see also thread names which flask internally creates. That is the `[Thread: Thread-2-139887733913344]`